# How does spring know what to inject in a generic list?

Tags: spring

Given that code fragment

```
@Service

public class MapUnitsService {
    @Autowired  
    private List<UnitMapping> unitMappings;
...
```

How does spring know what to inject into unitMappings since the type information is gone at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier than expected, since reflection provides the required information:

```
public class Main {

    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,   NoSuchFieldException {

            Field field = Main.class.getDeclaredField("test");

            System.out.println(field.getGenericType().getTypeName());
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically spring will inject all the beans in the application context of that type .

Comment: Yes I know, but how does Spring know at runtime that  the List is a  List<UnitMapping> ? I thought the types are erased?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define bean:

```
@Bean
List<UnitMapping> unitMappings(){
    return new UnitMapping(); 
}
```

Spring 4.0 will automatically inject consider generics as a form of @Qualifier, as below:

```
    @Autowired  
    private List<UnitMapping> unitMappings;
```

Class which provides responsible for generic inject is [ResolvableType](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html)

[Spring Framework 4.0 and Java Generics](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics)